# From RDD of array of arrays into dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

After doing some operation, I got a rdd (like following one) of array(any)  where all the value are of type *Int expect 3,8 and 13* are of type string.

```
Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15))
```

Use following code for your reference:

```
var exp = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1,2,"3",4,5),Array(6,7,"8",9,10),Array(11,12,"13",14,15)))
```

---

Now I am trying to create a dataframe from this array using case class where columns name and case class is following:

```
case class specialchar(alpha:Int,beta:Int,gamma:String,theta:Int,zeta:Int)
```

---

I need help how we can iterate through the rdd of Array[Array[Any]] and store in dataframe. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Udf's to handle `Any`.

```
def toInt(x: Any): Option[Int] = x match {
  case i: Int => Some(i)
  case _ => None
}

def toStr(x: Any): Option[String] = x match {
  case i: String => Some(i)
  case _ => None
}
```

Case classes and converting Array to Df.

```
var exp = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1,2,"3",4,5),Array(6,7,"8",9,10),Array(11,12,"13",14,15)))
case class specialchar(alpha:Int,beta:Int,gamma:String,theta:Int,zeta:Int)  

var specialCharDf = Seq.empty[specialchar].toDF

exp.collect().foreach(x => {
    val a:Int = toInt(x(0)).getOrElse(1)
    val b:Int = toInt(x(1)).getOrElse(1)
    val c:String = toStr(x(2)).getOrElse("1")
    val d:Int = toInt(x(3)).getOrElse(1)
    val e:Int = toInt(x(4)).getOrElse(1)

    println(a, b, c, d, e)

    val specialcharTempDf =  Seq(specialchar(a,b,c,d,e)).toDF
    specialCharDf = specialcharTempDf.union(specialCharDf)
})

specialCharDf.printSchema() //follows schema desired.
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT -- akhil mentioned that at the end, they should all be in integers. The new solution is below:

```
    var exp = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1,2,"3",4,5),Array(6,7,"8",9,10),Array(11,12,"13",14,15)))
    case class specialchar(alpha:Int,beta:Int,gamma:Int,theta:Int,zeta:Int)  

    var specialCharDf = Seq.empty[specialchar].toDF

exp.collect().foreach(x => {
    val a:Int = toInt(x(0)).getOrElse(1)
    val b:Int = toInt(x(1)).getOrElse(1)
    val c:String = toStr(x(2)).getOrElse("1")
    val f = c.toInt
    val d:Int = toInt(x(3)).getOrElse(1)
    val e:Int = toInt(x(4)).getOrElse(1)

    println(a, b, f, d, e)

    val specialcharTempDf =  Seq(specialchar(a,b,f,d,e)).toDF
    specialCharDf = specialcharTempDf.union(specialCharDf)
})

specialCharDf.printSchema() //follows schema desired.
```

Comment: What if Instead of above situation the numbers 3,8 and 13 which are in string format should be converted into integer?

Comment: @Akhil Instead of doing `val c:String = toStr(x(2)).getOrElse("1")` you would just do `val c:Int = toInt(x(2)).getOrElse(1)`. You would need to change the case case to `gamma:Int` too.

Comment: I have tried your suggested change in the original code but get the final output  as following.
(1,2,1,4,5)(6,7,1,9,10)(11,12,1,14,15)
The gamma column is getting the values from .getOrElse(1) from c variable. This is  because the string value in RDD array is not supportive to toInt().
I think so..

Comment: @Akhil check the new solution. I think I misunderstood you above.

Comment: The code **var specialCharDf = Seq.empty[specialchar].toDF** is running fine in REPL mode  but throwing error in the Ecllipse's Scala IDE. The error is showing like **value toDF is not a member of  Seq[specialchar]** Any suggestion to this?

Comment: @Akhil you need to define the case class outside of where you call `toDf`. If you are in a notebook style environment, put the case class in a cell above where you call `var specialCharDf = Seq.empty[specialchar].toDf`. Try importing `import spark.implicits._` as well.

Comment: I have already put case class below where all imports are placed(outside the main). I am using Scala IDE  and having spark version 2.1.1. While importing `import spark.implicits._` error showing **not found: object spark** but the sparkConf and sparkContext imported successfully.  I tried importing all the jars from spark to the project but still getting an error. On the contrary the code is running fine in spark's REPL mode.